# MySQL update 2 fields, which have one same foreign key id. but the other foreign key is different

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
 - id: (foreign key of another table)
 - room_id: foreign_key_1
 - department_id: foreign_key_2
```

one room can belong to 2 departments, so I have 2 rows:

```
 - id : 1
 - room_id: 100
 - department_id: 1 (xxx)
```

and

```
 - id: 2 
 - room_id: 100
 - department_id: 2 (xyz)
```

Now I have to update these records with new values: `room 100 : dept 1 (new -
 xxx)` and `room 100 :dept 5 (new - abc)`. Expected values:

```
 - id : 1
 - room_id: 100
 - department_id: 1 (new - xxx)
```

and

```
 - id: 2 
 - room_id: 100
 - department_id: 5 (new - abc)
```

How can I do this in MySQL? Suppose I don't know any rows in the table. I only know the table's structure.

Comment: can you post expected output?

Comment: There is no "first", tables have no order. Also, read the documentation for the update command. Show an example with exact input & table values before and after.

Comment: @DheerajKumar I have updated my question

Comment: @philipxyI updated with my input and output

Comment: do you check for dept_id before updating it to new value in your where clause?? ex: update---------- where dept_id=1 (xxx)

Comment: @DheerajKumar I must update the row by using "where room_id = 100"

Comment: You want to update departmentids of room based on roomid. In that case, you must have some condition of dept id as well in your where clause. Else it will update all the deptids for a roomid. Other way is to change your schema and apply normalizaiton.

Comment: @DheerajKumar those conditions made me confused when I tried to update the table.

Comment: You have change schema then. Instead of working with roomid, work with deptid. have a table with columns as id, dept id, and roomid. and update this table based on deptid. This is the way around I see.

Comment: @DheerajKumar sorry I forgot to mention that dept_id have been updated before so I can't update using dept_id

Comment: Changing schema would be only way. You can't achieve this with current schema

Comment: You are not clear. Does your "suppose ..." refer to the same question, or ask a different question? Also, do not clarify in comments, edit your question. Also please read & act on [mcve].